# Python 3: For loop comparing strings in lists

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, for-loop

I have a simple script that takes any number of lists, containing any number of items. I need to get iterate over these lists and display values which appear in more than one list, here is what I have so far:

```
def lists(*usrin):

# STRINGS IN MULTIPLE LISTS
repeat_strings = set()
for a, b in itertools.combinations(usrin, 2):
    repeat_strings.update(set(a).intersection(b))
    print(', ' .join(repeat_strings))
```

As a user if I pass the function the following arguments:

```
lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'], ['gn'])
```

I would expect to get:

```
gn, gh
```

As the output, however I get:

```
gh
gh
gn, gh
```

I'm not sure where the first two 'gh' are coming from.

If I add another list to, making the function call looks like this:

```
lists(['g', 'gh', 'ghj', 'g'], ['j', 'ju', 'gh', 'gk', 'gn'], ['gn'], ['g', 'gk'])
```

I would expect to get:

```
g, gn, gk, gh
```

But instead get:

```
gh
gh
g, gh
g, gn, gh
g, gn, gk, gh
g, gn, gk, gh
```

Which makes me think that I'm misunderstanding the for loop I've made, could anyone explain what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The print statement is responsible of the display you see. It is executed for each loop, so it represents the construction of your list step by step. Otherwise, your algorithm is correct. Try this to avoid intermediate print :

```
def lists(*usrin):

    # STRINGS IN MULTIPLE LISTS
    repeat_strings = set()
    for a, b in itertools.combinations(usrin, 2):
        repeat_strings.update(set(a).intersection(b))
    print(', ' .join(repeat_strings))
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't notice that.. Sometimes you just need another pair of eyes. Thank you!

Comment: When facing to a problem, try to explain it to your teddy bear/mouse/pen/colleague/whoever 'stupid' enough to force you to explain it in detail, and in general in the middle of the explanation, you catch the problem :)